# Image Blink and Timer to trap the mouseClicked() event - Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, timer, jlabel

I am coding a game right now, in which an image blinks on the `JFrame` and every time when it appears the user has to click on a button to record his time of reaction.

Each reaction time has to be stored.

Problems faced:

- couldn't blink the image using Swing Timer class
- How to trap mouseclicked() event every time the image appears while blinking? And how to record the time of click, in array or collections?

this is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


class Test

{

    JFrame fr, fr1;

    JLabel startLabel, clickArea, timerLocation;

    ImageIcon ic;

    JButton click, restart, quit;

    JPanel jp1, jp2, jp3;

    boolean showpic = false;

    Timer timer;

    Test()

    {

        fr= new JFrame("Advanced Mode: Reflex Master");

        fr.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        fr.setSize(800,800);

        fr.setVisible(true);

        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jp1= new JPanel();

        startLabel = new JLabel("Click on the image, whenever it appears! And be QUICK!!!", JLabel.CENTER);

        startLabel.setOpaque(true);

        startLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        startLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 26));

        startLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        startLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        jp1.add(startLabel);

        jp1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        /*timerLocation = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("time.png"));

        timerLocation.setOpaque(true);

        timerLocation.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        jp1.add(timerLocation);*/

        fr.add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        jp2 = new JPanel();

        GridLayout gL = new GridLayout(0,1);

        jp2.setLayout(gL);

        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("time.png");

        clickArea = new JLabel(ic);

        fr.add(clickArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        click = new JButton("Click Here!");
        jp2.add(click);
        ActionListener aL = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if(clickArea != null)
                {
                    if(!showpic)
                    {
                        clickArea.setVisible(false);
                    }
                    clickArea.setVisible(true);
                    showpic = !showpic; 
                }
                else
                {
                    clickArea.setText("Picture not available");
                }
            }

        };

        timer = new Timer(600, aL);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
        restart = new JButton("Restart");
        jp2.add(restart);
        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        jp2.add(quit);
        click.setFocusable(false);
        restart.setFocusable(false);
        quit.setFocusable(false);
        fr.add(jp2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jp3 = new JPanel();
        jp3.add(new JLabel("Time: "));
        timerLocation = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jp3.add(timerLocation);
        fr.add(jp3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        new CountDownTimer(this).start();
        fr.pack();
        fr.setResizable(false);
    }

    public void settimerLocationText(String text)
    {
        timerLocation.setText(text);
    }

    public void endTimerGUI()
    {
        timer.stop();
        fr1= new JFrame("Result");
        fr1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        fr1.setVisible(true);
        fr1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Test();
    }

}

class CountDownTimer 

{

private static final int TIMER_PERIOD = 1000;

   protected static final int MAX_COUNT = 60;

   private Test test; // holds a reference to the Test class

   private int count;


   public CountDownTimer(Test test)

   {

      this.test = test; // initializes the reference to the Test class.

      String text = "(" + (MAX_COUNT - count) + ") seconds left";

      test.settimerLocationText(text);


   }


   public void start()
 {

      new Timer(TIMER_PERIOD, new ActionListener()
 {

         @Override

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {

            if (count < MAX_COUNT)
 {


 count++;
               String text = "(" + (MAX_COUNT - count) + ") seconds left";

               test.settimerLocationText(text); // uses the reference to 

            }

else 
{

               ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();

               test.endTimerGUI();

            }

         }

      }).start();

   }


}
enter code here
```

Comment: 1)  Why are you blinking the image?  Just show the image.  2) Get the time when you show the image.  Get the time in the action listener of the button.  Subtract times to get reaction time.  If negative, ignore.  If positive, store the reaction times in milliseconds in a List<Integer>

Comment: Sir, this is what problem, I'm facing. I'm unable to figure out how to bind timer with action listener of the button.
Kindly provide some part of the code for my understanding and after that i'll make my own code.
Thank you

Comment: you said you `couldn't` which means you have tried and failed. So show us the failed code

Comment: ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("time.png");
clickArea = new JLabel(ic);
fr.add(clickArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
click = new JButton("Click Here!");
jp2.add(click);
ActionListener aL = new ActionListener()
{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
  if(clickArea != null)
    {
  if(!showpic)
     {
      clickArea.setVisible(false);
     }
     clickArea.setVisible(true);
     showpic = !showpic; 
    }
    else
    {
     clickArea.setText("Picture not available");
    }
   }
   
  };
  
  timer = new Timer(600, aL);
  timer.setRepeats(true);
  timer.start();

Comment: Unfortunately, the question was put on hold as I was typing my answer.  You can find the code I put together for you on http://www.java-articles.info/images/ReactionTimer.zip  Sorry, the explanation disappeared.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your reply, I am new to this website, I didn't know how to put up questions and code in big forums. That's why I forgot to attach my code. I think that before putting the questions on hold, the senior professionals should tell the seeker what's missing in the question. How will a beginner like me learn then?
Now that I have attached my code. Please help to rectify it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  The OP has now added code.  I still feel it is a little too broad for SO, but have voted to reopen.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thanks. I've had 3 questions put on hold while I was answering them this week.  It gets frustrating at times.  I guess I need to put placeholder answers, then update them.